# Regress values inside the bounding boxes to predict a value in Object Detection

Tags: neural-network, regression, convolutional-neural-network

I am currently working on an object detection task. I have a dataset of grayscale and depth images.  The annotation format is $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, class, depth$. I calculated this depth (of each object/bounding box) using a clustering algorithm and depth image.

My plan is to use the grayscale images to detect the bounding boxes and the class labels using a pre-trained CNN.

Furthermore, I would like to use the depth images to predict the depth (ground truth values in the dataset as mentioned above). For this task, my plan is to build a Regression-based Neural Network that regresses the depth values inside the bounding boxes of the depth image and compares them to the ground truth values. A RMSE loss function can be used to keep track of the predictions. Because I cannot post the real depth image here, I am posting a sample image, and please consider that to be the depth image just for explanation's sake. In the image, one can see the bounding boxes. I would like to use a neural network that regresses the values inside each bounding box and predicts the depth value. This predicted depth value should then be compared to the ground truth depth value from the dataset, and so on...

[image]

How do I go about making this Regression-based NN and is there a better alternative?